Doesn't work handling "JavaScript heap out of memory" error in nodejs/nestjs
I have nestjs app and it crashed with "out of memory". I increased memory ofc, but I need to handle this error also. I tried to make a primitive example of nodejs(macos if it depends) and it also doesn't work for me:
function handleError(error) {
    console.error('Unhandled error occurred:', error.message);
    console.error(error.stack);

    process.exit(1);
}

function handle(signal) {
    console.log(`Received signal: ${signal}`);
}

process.on('SIGABRT', handle);
process.on('SIGINT', handle);
process.on('SIGTERM', handle);
process.on('uncaughtException', handleError);
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
    handleError(reason instanceof Error ? reason : new Error(String(reason)));
});

const largeArray = [];
try {
    while (true) {
        largeArray.push(new Array(1000000).fill('leak'));
        console.log(largeArray.length);
    }
} catch (err) {
    handleError(err);
}

I tried to run as "/usr/local/bin/node --max-old-space-size=128 --trace-gc memoryleak.js"
and i have something like this:
1
[94227:0x158008000]       15 ms: Scavenge 10.7 (11.6) -> 10.6 (12.6) MB, 0.88 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
2
[94227:0x158008000]       17 ms: Scavenge 18.2 (20.3) -> 18.2 (23.0) MB, 0.71 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
3
[94227:0x158008000]       18 ms: Scavenge 25.8 (30.7) -> 25.8 (34.7) MB, 0.67 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
4
[94227:0x158008000]       20 ms: Scavenge 33.4 (42.3) -> 33.4 (50.3) MB, 0.79 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
5
[94227:0x158008000]       24 ms: Scavenge 41.1 (57.9) -> 41.0 (57.9) MB, 0.62 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
6
[94227:0x158008000]       28 ms: Scavenge 48.7 (65.6) -> 48.7 (81.6) MB, 2.42 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
7
8
[94227:0x158008000]       35 ms: Scavenge 64.0 (96.9) -> 63.9 (96.9) MB, 1.17 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
9
10
[94227:0x158008000]       47 ms: Scavenge 79.2 (112.1) -> 79.3 (112.1) MB, 1.58 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
[94227:0x158008000]       83 ms: Mark-Compact 86.9 (119.8) -> 86.6 (119.3) MB, 31.12 / 0.00 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 48 ms) (average mu = 0.626, current mu = 0.626) finalize incremental marking via stack guard; GC in old space requested
11
12
13
[94227:0x158008000]       87 ms: Scavenge 102.0 (134.6) -> 102.0 (134.6) MB, 1.42 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.626, current mu = 0.626) allocation failure; 
14
15
[94227:0x158008000]      110 ms: Mark-Compact 117.2 (149.8) -> 117.1 (149.8) MB, 19.83 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.535, current mu = 0.248) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
16
17
[94227:0x158008000]      158 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 132.4 (165.1) -> 132.4 (134.1) MB, 43.38 / 0.00 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 47 ms) (average mu = 0.334, current mu = 0.107) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed

<--- Last few GCs --->

[94227:0x158008000]      110 ms: Mark-Compact 117.2 (149.8) -> 117.1 (149.8) MB, 19.83 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.535, current mu = 0.248) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
[94227:0x158008000]      158 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 132.4 (165.1) -> 132.4 (134.1) MB, 43.38 / 0.00 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 47 ms) (average mu = 0.334, current mu = 0.107) al

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0x10482c0bc node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x1049e49f8 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x104bc5164 v8::internal::Heap::stack() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x104bc3374 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x104bba660 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x104bbaefc v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x104b9e580 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x104b91a4c v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x104d21e04 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastHoleySmiElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)1>>::ConvertElementsWithCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>, v8::internal::ElementsKind, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x104d21c70 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastHoleySmiElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)1>>::GrowCapacityAndConvertImpl(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x104d219cc v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastHoleySmiElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)1>>::SetLengthImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x104d1fb24 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastHoleySmiElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)1>>::SetLength(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>, unsigned int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x104e65a80 v8::internal::JSArray::SetLength(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>, unsigned int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x104cf43b4 v8::internal::ArrayConstructInitializeElements(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>, v8::internal::Arguments<(v8::internal::ArgumentsType)1>*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x104f5fcb4 v8::internal::Runtime_NewArray(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
16: 0x105307954 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
17: 0x10527d858 construct_stub_invoke_deopt_addr [/usr/local/bin/node]
18: 0x1053d870c Builtins_ConstructHandler [/usr/local/bin/node]
19: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
20: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
21: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
22: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
23: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
24: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
25: 0x10527cb84 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
26: 0x10527a8ac Builtins_JSEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
27: 0x10527a594 Builtins_JSEntry [/usr/local/bin/node]
28: 0x104b26ef8 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::Invoke(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeParams const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
29: 0x104b26478 v8::internal::Execution::Call(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
30: 0x1049fe404 v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
31: 0x10480366c node::builtins::BuiltinLoader::CompileAndCall(v8::Local<v8::Context>, char const*, node::Realm*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
32: 0x10489fd80 node::Realm::ExecuteBootstrapper(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
33: 0x1047e7a20 node::StartExecution(node::Environment*, std::__1::function<v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> (node::StartExecutionCallbackInfo const&)>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
34: 0x104751350 node::LoadEnvironment(node::Environment*, std::__1::function<v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> (node::StartExecutionCallbackInfo const&)>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
35: 0x10486b724 node::NodeMainInstance::Run(node::ExitCode*, node::Environment*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
36: 0x10486b4d4 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/usr/local/bin/node]
37: 0x1047eab48 node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
38: 0x190cee0e0 start [/usr/lib/dyld]
zsh: abort      /usr/local/bin/node --max-old-space-size=128 --trace-gc 

How can I be guaranteed to handle this error or it can depends on speed of system and it could be raise before handling?
In nestjs I also tried to use enableShutdownHooks() and it didn't help

"but I need to handle this error also" - why? What makes you assume that the crash is recoverable at all?

@Bergi I want to try to disconnect from at least a few services(redis, mongo,...) in time. When I use enableShutdownHooks() and try to kill app- it's ok and I can disconnect from services, but I want to try to disconenct in that case. Mb I cant do that.

When I googled this case people say that handle uncaughtException and unhandledRejection can help me, but it's not works for me

There are no connections to close. When the process crashes, the connections are simply dropped. And no, this is not an exception from javascript code that could be caught from other javascript code - it is a fatal crash of the runtime.
